# Adding images in a lightbox in a nav menu

Tags: html, lightbox, lightbox2, bootstrap-lightbox

I've been tasked to slightly edit an old, simple, static webpage. I need to add a few images to a lightbox. The previous developer had used lightbox2 in the navigational menu so that when clicked a popup window would show a restaurant menu.

Their HTML code is like this:

```html
<div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center d-flex">          
 <nav>
  <ul class="nav-menu">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="img/img1.jpg" data-lightbox="menu" data-title="Restaurant Menu">Menu</a></li>                         
  </ul>
 </nav>
  <a href="img/img2.jpg" data-lightbox="menu" data-title="Restaurant Menu"></a>                 
</div>
```

I can see that they've put a second lightbox image right outside the nav menu thus leading it to never loading in the lightbox. I've tried to put it right next to the first image link in the li tag but it didn't work.

The question is how can I add a few images to this lightbox without affecting the layout and with the lightbox being operational for more than just one photo?

The site is also using jquery 2.2.4 and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong, the previous developer had set a wrong value for "albumLabel" in the option method, crashing the lightbox. I've edited it and now it works as it should.